# Fetch count of documents in mongoDB with a list of values for a field

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a field say 'name' and same name can be present in multiple documents in collection C1. Now, I have list of names and for each name I want to find the number of documents it is present in with lesser number of DB queries.

I am trying to do with grouping but this doesnt work

```
db.campaignDetails.aggregate({"$group" : {_id: {name:'abc'}, count:{$sum:1}}})
```

Comment: Lesser than what? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to do it in minimum queries.I can do with each name but that we make way too many DB calls.

Comment: I am trying to do with grouping but this doesnt work db.campaignDetails.aggregate({"$group" : {_id: {name:'abc'}, count:{$sum:1}}})

Answer (score 0):

if you want in one query to get all the names with the number of documents it appears in ("total"),  you can try this :

```
db.campaignDetails.aggregate({$group: {"_id" : "$name" , "total" : {$sum : 1}}})
```